# How do I set value of mid in Merge Sort?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have implemented merge sort algorithm, but it is throwing exception for some values and displaying right value of some values.
Ex: If I have input array as: 4 3 2 1 then it displays 1 2 3 4 correctly
However, for input: 1 3 5 2 4 6 it throws exception. I think it is because of my assignment of mid. Here is my implementation of `merge` function:

```
void mergeArr(int a[], int l, int mid, int r)
{
    int n1, n2;
    int i,j,k;
    int inv_count = 0;
    n1 = mid - l + 1;
    n2 = r - mid;
    int temp[r-l+1];
    int L[n1], R[n2];
    for(i = 0;i < n1;i++)
        L[i] = a[l+i];
    for(j = 0;j < n2;j++)
        R[j] = a[mid+j+1];
    i = j = 0;
    k = l;
    while(i<n1 && j<n2)
    {
       if(L[i] <= R[j])
            temp[k++] = L[i++];
        else
        {
            temp[k++] = R[j++];
            inv_count += (mid - i);
        }
    }
    while(i<n1)
        temp[k++] = L[i++];
    while(j<n2)
        temp[k++] = R[j++];
    for(i=l;i<=r;i++)
        a[i] = temp[i];
}
```

and `merge_sort` function:

```
void mergeSort(int a[], int l, int r)
{
    int inv_count = 0;
    if(l < r)
    {
        int mid;
        mid = (l + (r))/2;
        mergeSort(a,l,mid);
        mergeSort(a,mid+1,r);
        mergeArr(a,l,mid, r);
    }
    //return inv_count;
```

Comment: added language tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, replacing `inv_count += (mid - i)` to `inv_count += (n1 - i)` did the work as it makes sense